# Difference between a government job (either full-time or semi-government) and private sector in Pakistan

Tags: contracts, payscale, pakistan

What is the difference between a **government** job (either full-time or semi-government) and a **private sector job** in Pakistan? If an organization does not use the [BPS (Basic Pay Scale)](https://www.careermidway.com/blog/what-is-salary-of-government-employees-in-pakistan-46), will a job belong in a non-governmental category?

I am employee of [COMSTATS University](http://www.comsats.edu.pk/), Pakistan,
and I am not sure whether I am a government employee or not because we do not use the Basic Pay Scale (BPS).

Comment: *I am employee in comsats university pakistan and i am not sure whether we i am government employee or not beacuse we do not use pay scales of BPS* that sounds like a question you could/should ask your employer.

Comment: Please note that questions on company-specific policies are off-topic here. This question should probably be directed to your H.R. department for clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having worked in Pakistan as a contractor, I would like to say that you raise an important question.  It is important not only for you, but for foreigners who might want to work in Pakistan but are forbidden to work of a foreign government.

From my experience, people who are not under the BPS system are contractors who are still working under a government umbrella, but the employment rules are different.

In America we sometimes have the same sort of gray areas between government (federal, state, or local) and the private sector; for example, public universities, defense contractors, etc.

From what I know, you are not in an official government position if you are paid according to a different scale from the BPS.

Answer (score -1):

No idea, but in the UK we refer to them as "public sector", vs "private sector". Academia (universities) could be either. I don't think the *pay scales* question is relevant, as many private sector companies (e.g. banks) also have them.

Lots of assumptions on my part here, obviously.